# python - array length variable keeps changing into a 'none type'

Tags: arrays, binary-search, python-3.8

So I've been trying to make a program that uses binary search for school, however whenever I try to run it, it comes back with an error of 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType'

This is the code:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
find = 3
if len(arr)%2 != 0:
    half = int(len(arr)+1)
else:
    half = int(len(arr))
half = half/2
half = int(half)

while True:
    half = int(half)
    sort = arr[half]
    print(sort)
    if find < sort:
        half = print(half/2)
    elif find > sort:
        half = half+(half/2)
    elif find == sort:
        print(f"found at position {half}")
```

I clearly state that it is an integer, but it just doesn't work and I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the line `half = print(half/2)`. print is a function that doesn't return anything (therefore it returns `None`), and you are assigning None to half then. You probably mean `half = half/2`, and if you want to print it, do so on the next line.

Also, take a look at the difference between `/` and `//` in python. If you use `//` to divide by two, it will always return an integer and you won't need to manually convert it to an int using `half = int(half)`.